# Laravel - SUM of cloumns by 2 dates and customer_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to get SUM amount, service_charge, and GST by between 2 dates(payment_date), customer_id, and pay status 1

These are my tables

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I want to get output to be like this :

[image]

Help me to write the laravel model function. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what have you tried ? where is the issue exactly ? your relation are simple 1 to many https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Thanks.  I am a beginner in laravel and I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this can help you to build the query.

```
DB::table('ss_transaction')
     ->join('ss_service_charge','ss_service_charge.ss_transaction_id','ss_transaction.id')
      ->select(
        'payment_date',
        'total_amount',
        "total_service_charge", 
        "total_gst", 
       DB::raw('COUNT(amount) as Shipment_count'))
      ->groupBy('payment_date')
      ->where('pay_status',1)
      ->get();
```

Comment: I am not expecting this result. I am already mentioned above what result I need @Tayyab mehar

Comment: Check your last table as expected output. Have you tried this query? Show me your output with my query.